# Where is doc with twitter all permission

Tags: spring-social, spring-social-twitter

I am looking for all scopes for twitter, and i cant find :/
I find all permission for facebook, but can not find all permission for tweeter
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login

can you halp me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Twitter API is secured with OAuth 1.0a, which doesn't provide for scoping. Some APIs have extended OAuth 1.0a to support scope, but not Twitter. The closest thing that the Twitter has to scoping is Read/Write/Direct permission. But you set those in the application's configuration at Twitter, not at authorization time like you do with Facebook.

Comment: Hmm but it is possible to get user email from tweeter. Now i am run your spring social showcase, add some sysout in SignupController and tweeter do not send email address when you are authorized :/